# Command line sorting file content and redirecting output to the file

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, command-line, command

The file 'numbers' contains a list of numbers.  Write a command to place
the largest one of those numbers into the file 'largest' (there should be
nothing else in that file). Do not use the 'head' command in your answer.

I am trying **sort numbers | tail > largest**

Comment: sort numbers | tail -n 1 > largest, works

Comment: What is your problem here? May be you are missing `-n` option to use numeric sort?

Comment: There's no need to completely sort a list of numbers just to find the max.   Assuming one number per line:  `awk 'NR==1{max=$0} max < $0 { max = $0 } END { print max }' numbers > largest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write like this:

```
sort -n numbers | tail > largest
```

Comment: Problem was i didn't type -n flag for numbers

Answer (score 1):

sort -n numbers | tail -1 > largest

Comment: Surrounding your answer by some explanation would seriously improve its quality.